# Не могу запустить 'django-admin shell'

Tags: python, django

Не могу запустить `django-admin shell`

Выдаёт в ответ на это следующее сообщение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myvenv/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N,
    but settings are not configured. You must either define the
    environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
    settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы заглянете в файл `manage.py`, то увидите там подобную строчку:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "вашпроект.settings")
```

А теперь внимательно прочитайте текст вашей ошибки:

```
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

Когда вы запускаете `manage.py`, он автоматически «defines the environment variable» вместо вас.

Когда же вы запускаете `django-admin`, прописать переменную окружения за вас некому. Чтобы `django-admin` заработал, вы должны сделать это самостоятельно тем или иным образом:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=вашпроект.settings
django-admin shell
```

Или можно через аргумент:

```
django-admin shell --settings=вашпроект.settings
```

`manage.py` — это такой же `django-admin`, но с заранее прописанной этой переменной окружения.

И про это всё в общем-то упоминается в документации: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/

Comment: Спасибо!) Жаль не могу из за репутации поставить тебе "+" в карму

Comment: @КрисРэкфилд но всегда можно поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа

Comment: Окаааай) давно меня так не учили)
Спасибо тебе, и успехов)))

Answer (score -1):

Всё, отбой, заработало с помощью 'python manage.py shell'

Мало ли кому поможет, а то в руководстве Django 2.0 используется и такой способ, только он не робит)

Comment: В последнем предложении английском по белому написано, почему не робит, непонятно что вам непонятно)

Comment: Если честно, то не очень понял, что именно пошло не так. Если можете объяснить - буду благодарен.

Если бы понимал, то данный вопрос бы тут не появился